# Yeoman LiveReload support for templates?

Tags: yeoman, livereload

LiveReload is awesome ([now that it works](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/347) :). The only part that doesn't seem to be working is when I change template files, I have to manually refresh. Any way to get that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it [livereloads the top-level HTML files](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js#L51). If you have it nested in a subfolder you'll need to update the globbing. You also need to make sure you've added the template compiling grunt task to [watch](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js#L29).

Comment: I'm just using the out of the box configuration with the backbone generator. Seems like that should handle that for me. :)

Comment: Open a ticket on that repo ;)

Comment: Fixed [livereload on template files](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/commit/c3f3e1b85518c66e0b9b7da253d04d6a289e827b)